# Mean of data frame columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the a `data.frame` with different year data for a set of observations. The name of the columns is the year, and the repeated year has is identified by the year followed by a `".1"` (`2008` and `2008.1` the repeated year).

The `dput()` of for the first observation of the `data.frame` is the following:

```
structure(list(ID = 2174L, `1992` = 0L, `1993` = 0L, `1994` = 0L, 
    `1994.1` = 0L, `1995` = 0L, `1996` = 0L, `1997` = 0L, `1998` = 0L, 
    `1999` = 0L, `1997.1` = 0L, `1998.1` = 0L, `1999.1` = 0L, 
    `2000` = 0L, `2001` = 0L, `2002` = 0L, `2003` = 0L, `2000.1` = 0L, 
    `2001.1` = 0L, `2002.1` = 0L, `2003.1` = 0L, `2004` = 0L, 
    `2005` = 0L, `2006` = 0L, `2007` = 0L, `2008` = 0L, `2004.1` = 0L, 
    `2005.1` = 0L, `2006.1` = 0L, `2007.1` = 0L, `2008.1` = 0L, 
    `2009` = 0L, `2010` = 0L, `2011` = 0L, `2012` = 0L, `2013` = 0L, 
    altura_mean_30arc = 341, dist_p = -1239.46778549383, dist_capital = 310537.289055982, 
    municode = 428, slope = 0.109233340937795, dist_f = -54589.0213329769), .Names = c("ID", 
"1992", "1993", "1994", "1994.1", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", 
"1999", "1997.1", "1998.1", "1999.1", "2000", "2001", "2002", 
"2003", "2000.1", "2001.1", "2002.1", "2003.1", "2004", "2005", 
"2006", "2007", "2008", "2004.1", "2005.1", "2006.1", "2007.1", 
"2008.1", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "altura_mean_30arc", 
"dist_p", "dist_capital", "municode", "slope", "dist_f"), row.names = 2174L, class = "data.frame")
```

I want to calculate the mean of the year and the repeated year (2008 and 2008.1). To simplify the process I tried a loop for every repeated year:

```
 duplicated_years <-  c("1994", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008")
 duplicated_years2 <- str_c(duplicated_years, "1", sep = ".")
 for(i in as.numeric(duplicated_years)){ 
  for(j in as.numeric(duplicated_years2)){
    df[, str_c(i, "mean", sep="_")] <- ((df$i + df$j) / 2)
  }  
}
```

But the result is a set of new variables with NA's. I know I can use `rowMean()` instead, but the indexing is quite difficult for me

Comment: Do you want it by `ID` too?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. Thats why I am thinking in the `rowMeans` option

Comment: Did that help you in any way? If not, I'll delete.

Comment: Well, I did use your code, but I decided to use 

`for(i in duplicated_years){ 
 merge_rasters_dataframes[, i] <- rowMeans(merge_rasters_dataframes[, which(names(merge_rasters_dataframes) == i) : which(names(merge_rasters_dataframes) == str_c(i, 1, sep = "."))])
}`

It seems cleaner to me, but I recognize that is not an efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

When you work with a wide format and have many columns to operate on row wise, it is better (in R) to convert to a long format and operate on a single column instead. Then converting back to a wide form (if needed) is pretty straight forward

For instance, here's a way finding all the columns containing a year

```
colindex <- grep("\\d{4}", names(df))
```

Then, using `data.table` we can select those (with `ID` too), `melt` it to a long format, calculate the means per user/year, while converting back to a wide format.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df)[, c(1L,  colindex),  with = FALSE], id = 1L), 
      ID ~ sub("\\..*", "", variable), value.var = "value", mean)
#      ID 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013
# 1: 2174    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: You don't need to convert `df` to a data.table. Though, when not, `sub("\\..*", "", variable)` gives a parse error, but using `sub("\\.\\d", "", variable)` instead does not... must be a bug ?

Comment: @Cath Welp, you do. If you''ll look into the source code of `data.table::melt` you will notice that it triggers `reshape2::melt` for `data.frame`s. This will probably also explain the error which comes from `reshape2` rather from `data.table`

Comment: ok I'm sorry I need to ask : that wouldn't give the same output ?

Comment: @Cath maybe, I haven't tested. But it will use different functions though, while I always prefer the most optimized one.